# Ionic CallNumber.callNumber() promise return "Ok" instead of the ussdResponse

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ussd

I'am on a Ionic React project an will like to run USSD code and process the response in other to automate some process.
I first use the react-native-ussd npm package but it sames to not be compatible with ionic react projet (and instead react-native project). Therefore, I got ionic call-number as a functional package for this but I dont know how to get the ussd response to process it. The callNumber() promise function return "Ok" instead of the ussd response.
Can some one help me to resolve this issue?
Thank in avance for your participation.

```
  async handleSubmitForm(e:any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({inProccess: true});
    let granted = await AndroidPermissions.checkPermission(AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.CALL_PHONE)
    .then(
      isGranted => {
        return true;
      },
      notGranted => {
        return false;
      }
    )
    .catch(raison => {
      return false;
    });
    if (granted) {
      let res = await CallNumber.callNumber(this.state.ussdCode, false);
      prompt(this.state.ussdResponse);
      alert(JSON.stringify(res));
    }
    else {
      alert( "Vous n'avez pas donné les autorisations requises. Vous ne pouvez pas utiliser l'application." );
    }
    this.setState({inProccess: false});
  }
```

Comment: did you find any solution ? im looking for this too and cant seem to make it work

Comment: a java/kotlin library has been made these purposes https://github.com/romellfudi/VoIpUSSD

Comment: @Spidy Thank for this information. Is there any way or a good documentation to integrate the native code librarie in an ionic project ?